# Change the background image of each item(vcard in this example) using XML data (store in XML tag as url) XSLT or CSS

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XML file that store visiting card data and I linked it to a XSL file to display the information as visiting cards.I also need to set its' (visiting card) background image using the URL(path) stored in xml files' element `<image>imageURL.jpg</image>`.

[image: Visiting cards(Browser=IExplorer)]

this is my XML code(vcards.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="style.xsl"?>
<vcards>
<vcard>
<position>Manager</position>
<address>Poddala,Galle</address>
<name>G.S Gamage</name>
<email>gamage@hotmail.com</email>
<image>gamage.jpg</image>
</vcard>
<vcard>
<position>Accountent</position>
<address>Galle</address>
<name>S Rathnayake</name>
<email>rathnayake@gmail.com</email>
<image>rathnayake.jpg</image>
</vcard>
<vcard>
<position>Developer</position>
<address>Kelaniya</address>
<name>P.P Kariyawasam</name>
<email>pradeep@gmail.com</email>
<image>pradeep.jpg</image>
</vcard>
<vcard>
<position>Project Manager</position>
<address>Colombo 7</address>
<name>A.J.L Shamikara</name>
<email>shamikara@gmail.com</email>
<image>shamikara.jpg</image>
</vcard>
</vcards>
```

This is my XSL code(style.xsl)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
     <xsl:for-each select="vcards/vcard">
     <div style = "border: thick solid red; display:block; margin-top:25px; width:250px; height:150px;">
     <xsl:value-of select="name"/><br/>
     <xsl:value-of select="position"/><br/><br/>
     <xsl:value-of select="address"/>
     <p>Email:<xsl:value-of select="email"/></p><br/>  
    </div>     
      </xsl:for-each>
   </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I select XSLT for doing this task, please help any way with any other language like CSS,JavaScript... to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put the static part of the styles aside in a CSS stylesheet like thus ...

### Resource at "card-styles.css"

```
.v-card {
    border: thick solid red;
    margin-top:25px;
    width:250px;
    height:150px;
    }
```

... then this XSLT 1.0 stylesheet ...

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>v-cards</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="card-styles.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="vcards/vcard" />
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="vcard">
  <div
    class="v-card"
    style="background: url({image}) blue;">
    <xsl:value-of select="name" /><br/>
    <xsl:value-of select="position" /><br/>
    <br/>
    <xsl:value-of select="address" />
    <p>Email:<xsl:value-of select="email" /></p><br/>
  </div>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

... applied to this input document ...

```
<vcards>
    <vcard>
        <position>Manager</position>
        <address>Poddala,Galle</address>
        <name>G.S Gamage</name>
        <email>gamage@hotmail.com</email>
        <image>http://orig11.deviantart.net/c6f5/f/2009/194/f/6/hi_res_lined_paper_texture_by_merileekitty.jpg</image>
    </vcard>
    <vcard>
        <position>Accountent</position>
        <address>Galle</address>
        <name>S Rathnayake</name>
        <email>rathnayake@gmail.com</email>
        <image>rathnayake.jpg</image>
    </vcard>
    <vcard>
        <position>Developer</position>
        <address>Kelaniya</address>
        <name>P.P Kariyawasam</name>
        <email>pradeep@gmail.com</email>
        <image>pradeep.jpg</image>
    </vcard>
    <vcard>
        <position>Project Manager</position>
        <address>Colombo 7</address>
        <name>A.J.L Shamikara</name>
        <email>shamikara@gmail.com</email>
        <image>shamikara.jpg</image>
    </vcard>
</vcards>
```

... will yield this output page ...

```css
.v-card {
    border: thick solid red;
    margin-top:25px;
    width:250px;
    height:150px;
    }
```

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
      <title>v-cards</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="card-styles.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="v-card" style="background: url(http://orig11.deviantart.net/c6f5/f/2009/194/f/6/hi_res_lined_paper_texture_by_merileekitty.jpg) blue;">G.S Gamage<br>Manager<br><br>Poddala,Galle
         <p>Email:gamage@hotmail.com</p><br></div>
      <div class="v-card" style="background: url(rathnayake.jpg) blue;">S Rathnayake<br>Accountent<br><br>Galle
         <p>Email:rathnayake@gmail.com</p><br></div>
      <div class="v-card" style="background: url(pradeep.jpg) blue;">P.P Kariyawasam<br>Developer<br><br>Kelaniya
         <p>Email:pradeep@gmail.com</p><br></div>
      <div class="v-card" style="background: url(shamikara.jpg) blue;">A.J.L Shamikara<br>Project Manager<br><br>Colombo 7
         <p>Email:shamikara@gmail.com</p><br></div>
   </body>
</html>
```